# Protecting a variable's data by const qualifier is of no use !!!?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char const_cvar1 = 'X';

    const char* ptr_to_const_char = &const_cvar1;

   // Simply a typecast of "ptr to a const char" to a "ptr to char" disables security !!!
    *(char *)ptr_to_const_char = 'S';
    printf("\n  Value of const char changed from X to : %c \n", const_cvar1);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:-

Value of const char changed from X to : S

I wonder if we can never rely on the const qualifier in C ? is it the fact ?

Comment: In retrospect, `const` should have been defined as *`readonly`*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's C. You can do a lot of things that are stupid, causes undefined behavior, is compiler/platform dependent etc.

casting away the const modifier is one of them. You are able to do so, but you get little guarantees as to what the result will be.

You could even cast it to just about anything, at your own risk.

```
 *(float *)ptr_to_const_char = 2.18;
```

However, const is not useless.

- It provides documentation, a programmer reading code where a pointer is declared const 
  can assume he can/should not modify what the pointer points to
- It can enable the compiler to do further optimizations

Just keep in mind that C does not protect you against yourself or others, it also gives you the ability to not honor the type system.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a fact. In fact, the compiler turns off const optimizations (few as there are) the moment it sees you casting away `const`, treating it like any other variable.

Answer (score 2):

`const` does not protect a variable. In fact, `const` does not even mean the variable will never change.

What it means is that **you**, the programmer, declare that **you** won't be writing to that part of memory. A memory-mapped input-only pin on a microchip might be represented by a variable qualified `const`, but it can still change if the voltage on the pin changes. (In fact, it will most likely be declared `const volatile`, which blew my mind the first time I saw it.) But the `const` means that you aren't allowed to write to it.

So if you break that promise — that you have no intention of writing to it — well then yes, of course that'll mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

You are programming in C and its always like that. While playing with pointers you need to be careful always.

Comment: This is not about pointers. It is about const declared variables

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
 char * const ptr_to_const_char
```

which is a constant pointer, not a pointer to a constant.

But that may only work in C++.

Comment: not quite. re-read the question. This is definitely _not_ the question

Comment: Interesting point @sehe -- the question is "I wonder if we can ever rely on the const qualifier in C, is it the fact"  This is pointing out how to rely on the const qualifier in C to stop the changing of the pointer, which is exactly the example he is giving of how it is not working.  Seems like I am exactly answering his question.  Everyone else is answering the question of why const char *x does not work the way he expects, but not pointing out there is a construct that does work the way he expects.

Comment: reread it again. This time don't stop before the commented line. He's _dereferencing_ a cv-casted pointer. The declared type of const_cvar1 or even whether ptr_to_const_char points to a valid memory region at all doesn't is utterly irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the content of a variable defined as const using such means is clearly UB. Avoid that.